# Backing up Linux to a Windows file system for later restoration

Tags: linux, backup, ext4, cpio, exfat

I need to backup / copy the files of my Linux installation to an external drive, so that I can restore them onto the new, larger disk.

The destination disk for the restoration is twice as large, and will have larger partitions, `ext4` and `linux-swap`.  Imaging the entire disk or its first partition is not really a good option, because both require later re-partitioning I'd like to avoid.

I am backing up to an exFAT-formatted drive, there are some issues with copying an ext4 Linux installation to exFAT though

- may destroy important hard links and fast* symbolic links from the `ext4` file system (will break Linux)
- won't preserve file ownership / permissions and `setuid` bits (will break Linux)
- won't preserve [capabilities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Capabilities) (will break Linux)
- won't preserve files extended attributes (xattrs) as well, as I believe many files have important information there (I don't care about Unix ACLs as I don't think I have any files using them)

If I copied the files directly to NTFS, FAT32, exFAT, etc, much of this metadata would be destroyed.

I don't care about compression since the original disk is smaller than my backup drive, but (GNU) `tar` seems to preserve only permissions/ownership (with `-p` and extract with `--same-owner`), links and xattrs, but file capability support is needed to backup modern Linux.

It seems the other main options are a CloneZilla Live system, and `cpio` which seems to create `tar` archives.

So the main options are

1. CloneZilla or just imaging the parition
2. `tar` itself, which may break things
3. `cpio`, which may be limited by the `tar` archive format?

*80,000 of the 83,000 symlinks are [fast symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147535/fast-and-slow-symlinks), and I'd like to preserve their fast-ness if possible

Comment: this would be easier to read if you cited at least one example why you think tar is shaky! current versions support xattrs, but it looks like as of 2016 it did not support "file capabilities". https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=771927

Comment: You say you cannot mount an external ext4 if you are not root.  I don't understand.  Why do you *want* to mount an external ext4, without being root?  You need to be root to copy the files and set their ownership etc. correctly.

Comment: If you want a nice GUI to be able to mount ext4, which will prompt for `sudo` password as needed, GNOME Disks is pretty awesome.  The package name should be `gnome-disk-utility`, in case you do not already have it installed.

Comment: @sourcejedi comment #1: i found a post yesterday (can't find it now, maybe on AU) mentioning how GNU tar "may or may not" properly archive permissions / ownership but i can't find it now, but i guess the `-p` and `--same-owner` options do the standard Unix permissions alright

Comment: @sourcejedi comment #2: the point is to have my "external USB disk for backup" formatted as ext4, so that I can directly copy my Linux system to it, and copy from it (those as root), and then also use it as a general purpose USB  for other non-backup files as a regular user

Comment: Why do you want to mount an external ext4 *without being root*?

Comment: @sourcejedi comment #3: ext4 partitions created with gparted as sudo can't be mounted by regular users but GNOME Disks-created ext4 partitions made as a regular user can be mounted by anyone, as I was wishing :) has become an X/Y question

Comment: for the purpose of this is to use the same ext4 partition for Linux backup(s) and for general USB purposes (where I would use FAT), but "general USB purposes" needs to be mountable by non-root, so I can put user-files like videos and whatever

Comment: rather than delete this I think i'll change it to the hypothetical next time where I only have an exFAT drive

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to find if there's anything that can copy "file capabilities" yet, other than taking a full filesystem image. `info cp` doesn't mention then anywhere, nor `rsync`.  The bugzilla thread suggests you can manually copy all xattrs, which is where they are stored, but that this is not advisable.  It also suggests that `star` can do it, but I don't have a recommendation for using `star` on Linux. Then I wonder how Linux package formats install "file capabilities" in the first place. DEB and RPM are both based on TAR format.

Comment: @sourcejedi `setcap` in the post-install script?

Comment: Have you considered making a sparse file (don't know if exfat can handle a single file large enough), formatting it as a ext4 file system, and mounting on loopback, then copying to that?  Would solve all the permissions loss, etc. issues.  Just don't know if exfat can handle a large enough single file.

Comment: @ivanivan main reason to use exFAT is file size upto 16 EiB, a huge improvement  over FAT32's 4GB limit :) make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @cat's comment, posting my comment as an answer -

Have you considered making a sparse file the size of your old installation, formatting it as a ext4 file system, and mounting on loopback, then copying to that? Would solve all the permissions loss, etc. issues. exFAT's filesize limit is 16EiB, surely large enough.

And per @cat's comment back to me, apparently a single file big enough won't be an issue ...